# How to rename a SharePoint File programaticaly

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, pnp-js

What is the best way to rename a file in SharePoint online without losing its version history?
Is it enough to update the "FileLeafRef" or Should I do a file.move?

Is there a Graph way for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use this to update file :

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: And update the "FileLeafRef" field? will this rename the file?

Comment: Yes,I have tested it.

Comment: Thanks Amos I will use it